# WSO2: SOAP services routing based on an method param

Tags: soap, routes, wso2

I have a simple scenario we've been trying to implement but we could not figure out how to do it.

Assume we have two services with the dame WSDL (below).

We want to create a proxy in WSO2 that exposes the same WSDL but routes the call to one of the two backend services based on the value of the IntValue.

```
IF IntValue = 1 THEN it calls
    http://localhost/WcfServiceDual_1/Service1.svc

ELSE IF IntValue = 2 THEN it calls
    http://localhost/WcfServiceDual_2/Service1.svc
```

After that the proxy returns the response that comes from the corresponding (called) service.

---

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="Service1" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost/WcfServiceDual_2/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost/WcfServiceDual_2/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost/WcfServiceDual_2/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfServiceDual_2"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetData"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataUsingDataContract"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataUsingDataContractResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IService1">
<wsdl:operation name="GetData">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData" message="tns:IService1_GetData_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetData_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetDataUsingDataContract">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContract" message="tns:IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContractResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" type="tns:IService1">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetData">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetDataUsingDataContract">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContract" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="Service1">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
<soap:address location="http://localhost/WcfServiceDual_2/Service1.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are hosting two instances of the same service ?

Anyway the logic you plan to have in the proxy is very simple. From the incoming request just extarct the param which you want to evaluate and based on that route the request to the differnt endpoint. You can use the [filter mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Filter+Mediator) for this.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="DualTest" transports="http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom" separator=",">
            <property name="MessageFlow" value="______"/>
         </log>
         <property xmlns:xs="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfServiceDual_1" xmlns:p="http://tempuri.org/" name="intValue" expression="//p:GetDataUsingDataContract/p:composite/xs:IntValue/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property xmlns:xs="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfServiceDual_1" xmlns:p="http://tempuri.org/" name="stringValue" expression="//p:GetDataUsingDataContract/p:composite/xs:StringValue/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="intValue" expression="$ctx:intValue"/>
            <property name="stringValue" expression="$ctx:stringValue"/>
         </log>
         <log level="custom" separator=",">
            <property name="MessageFlow" value="______"/>
            <property name="MessageFlow" value="\n======================= Sending Request To : Backend ======================="/>
         </log>
         <log level="full" separator=","/>
         <filter source="get-property('intValue')" regex="2">
            <then>
               <log level="custom" separator=",">
                  <property name="IF" value="*****    2"/>
               </log>
               <send>
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="http://Win8/WcfServiceDual_2/Service1.svc"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </then>
            <else>
               <log level="custom" separator=",">
                  <property name="ELSE" value="*****    1"/>
               </log>
               <send>
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="http://Win8/WcfServiceDual_1/Service1.svc"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </else>
         </filter>
         <log level="custom" separator=",">
            <property name="MessageFlow" value="______"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="http://localhost/WcfServiceDual_1/Service1.svc?wsdl"/>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```